# C# Verify Json string via signature and RSA public key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cryptography, signature, public-key

I'm creating an IAP plugin for the local Android market that I think has similar API as google play.

I build an Android side and it will return all response from the market to the unity `c# side`.
All part working fine but I can't figure out how to verify the signature of the response.

I'm new in cryptography and searching day to day about this.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

1. They use a `hash` algorithm to sign data and encrypt that `hash` with `private key`.
   I must decrypt signature with `public key` and compare hashes.

This is my `public key` (`Base64`):

```
MIHNMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4G7ADCBtwKBrwDltnT/AaF3oMt+F3lza5JEvce0GLS1L9v9Z53lQ3LNluGk0eI2ukgWm7tAiIOLQgn11Sb9mW2VWkYTWGnZ1AZtY0GwdUQJUr7u3CWNznE6XH4UCVOVhGDCLnFrG8BcfDelhcfReGZQ3izOefhc4Oq6vZf5PfLwximK+FH27fR6XL8vg3yyK4LSwT764Dfd6H3IGes6EdTx/C3C690jdyMvhi2Q3qBiqfepHzW/jV8CAwEAAQ==
```

This key is in `ASN.1` `DER` format.

I break it out and find this data:

```
SEQUENCE
  SEQUENCE
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 rsaEncryption(PKCS #1)
    NULL
  BIT STRING
    SEQUENCE
      INTEGER 969837669069837851043825067021609343597253227631794160042862620526559…
      INTEGER 65537
```

2. As I read on net first `INTEGER` is `Modules` and second `INTEGER` is `Exponent`

So in c# write a code like this =>

```
var parameter = new RSAParameters
{
    Modulus = HexToByteArray(/* "first_INTEGET" */),
    Exponent = BitConverter.GetBytes(/* "second_INTEGER" */)
};
```

Market send me a `Json` like this:

```
{"orderId": "0j8oJgE0Bett-neB", "purchaseToken": "0j8oJgE0Bett-neB", "developerPayload": "payload", "packageName": "com.some.market", "purchaseState": 0, "purchaseTime": 1520676644872, "productId": "card-1"}
```

The signature is like this:

```
hTFeQd25PZJ2DhGmXd0eO+C+oBeWsg983I4e5ztXtKAUrOIaNBaqAxHU3vW8acBs1I9fE5cxx/DI/sQGY4QSvpDnSm9aYz3do3joHPOXIVvXjSJfejxwzp9DKMUPd6LrgtxkaGevG+94NuKHFxpCdZlovEPXRJZyEznbASuYLqeW0KjP3jnvvw2O5iNlQRdh98h4Q18bSsaxq9zaRKExFLHkhNf/yO5m84kRB1G8
```

I'm searched for a method to do this but I don't know which method is true for me.
My verify code is this:

```
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rsa.ImportParameters(parameter);
    var hash = new SHA1Managed();
    bool dataOK = 
    rsa.VerifyData(hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)), CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signature));
}
```

3. How truly convert `signature` to `byte[]` to verify? (with encoding or what???)

I'm searching a lot but more search more confuse.

Am I going the wrong way or using wrong method or ...?

4. Why should workflow be complicated?

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks.

Comment: The modulus and the public exponent are simply decimal integers, not hex.

Comment: Thanks a lot, How can i convert this long decimal to byte array?

Comment: Create a BigInteger using it, then call the `ToByteArray()` method, then reverse the order of the bytes using a simple method you have to write. `BigInteger.ToByteArray()` returns a little-endian array but RSAParameters fields are big-endian.

Comment: From `MSDN` `BigInteger Available since 4.0`. I working with Unity with Mono similar to 3.5, Just 0.5 version distance to Solve this problem :)

Comment: signature is base-64 also by the way, why are you using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` for it?

Comment: Oh, I Saw '/' in it and forget that it's one of the Base64 chars. thanks.

Comment: As for "Why should workflow be complicated?" - that's because ASN.1 DER is not "native" format for .NET cryptography, for whatever reason. Usually other formats are used (such as raw public\private keys, or keys in xml format). So it's complicated because there is no built-in way to convert ASN.1 DER encoded key to format expected by .NET (but you can find code to do that on internet). Also you might have better luck with BouncyCastle (custom crypthography library for .NET).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'll answer in order:

1. > They use a hash algorithm to sign data and encrypt that hash with private key. I must decrypt signature with public key and compare hashes.

   No, that's not correct. You should use a signature verification method, as you're currently doing. Seeing signature as encryption of a hash is incorrect; even the latest RSA standards go out of their way to explain this. For RSA the internal padding method is different. For ECDSA there is no direct encryption/decryption possible using the same scheme.
2. > As I read on net first INTEGER is Modules and second INTEGER is Exponent

   Yes, although it is spelled modulus, not modules. It is the public exponent, there is also a private exponent for the private key. Also without the caps.
3. > How truly convert signature to byte[] to verify? (with encoding or what???)

   Standard Base 64 is already mentioned in the comment section. Note that the key and signature size are not common (but that's OK in itself).
4. > Why should workflow be complicated?

   Well, somebody has to code it in the end and crypto is hard. But to make it easier for you: the entire ASN.1 structure is called a SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure; if you look on the internet you will find pre-made code to import from such a structure.

To finally verify the structure: make sure that you use the correct signature format (RSA-PKCS#1 v1.5 or RSA-PSS) and that you know exactly which *binary* data is fed to the signature generation function. For instance, the signature over the JSON could be in ASCII or UTF-8 or it could be in UTF-16 LE or BE.

Better ask the creator of the signature.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that the signature itself **is** the byte array. How it is encoded depends on the protocol.

Comment: You're my new Cryptography hero. first hero in that type :)